# How to open mail client on iphone/android from browser (not compose window via mailto)

Tags: android, iphone, browser, mailto, inbox

Using "mailto" opens the compose window of the default mail client from mobile safari/android chrome

How do I get just the default mail client of the user's iphone/android to open instead of the compose window.

I plan to send an email to the user and provide a link on the browser page so user can open their mail client to see if they received the email.

This will greatly reduce the friction involved in asking the user to check their email inbox.

Comment: what is wrong with the `mailto:` on iOS? it should work well.

Comment: @holex mailto opens the compose window of the default mail client. I want to take the user to their mail inbox so they can see the mail I just sent. Imagine this was a "verify your email" message. I don't want them to see the compose window with the mailto:xxx@domain.com populated.

Comment: exactly, when you use the `mailto:` (without any additional addresses), the _Mail_ applicaiton will open with the compose window. this is the default behaviour of the _Mail_ application when it is called. you are not able to change it.

Comment: @holex looks like the behavior I want is not possible. thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?